# Auto-Brightness issue in Chromium & Edge on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, brightness

The latest version (1.0.3) appears to have an interesting quirk in that, on a secondary display, it adjust the contrast or brightness of pages that are largely white, making the any content too bright and difficult to read.

I have been able to revert to 1.0.2, which works, but it auto-updates again shortly after.

It only appears to affect Windows 10 and only secondary/tertiary displays. Primary display appears unaffected. This has been identified on laptops, so not sure if it's specifically down to a difference in resolution.

Any suggestions or work-arounds that people are using? Or has no-one else seen this issue?

Comment: There's a possibility that they have finally worked out how to do multiscreen display profile support [a couple of decades after it became standard on Mac] That's great… but only if both displays are correctly profiled. Drag a window from one display to the other, slowly. Is there a point at which it transitions between colours? [It may only happen when you let go of the drag with the majority of the window in one half, so test for that too]. If the transition is immediate, whilst dragging, then also test something simpler, like an empty Notepad page, for behaviour comparison.

Comment: Only affects the two browsers as far as my testing has confirmed. And it's not all pages, one example is https://google.com, can appear okay after a result is returned; another being https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/blank-tab/omfnbhnhakfflaaplgjbnfbpkibmcnpb (I'd noted that the edge extensions pages were doing it when hunting for something to resolve the issue).

Comment: I gave you quite detailed instructions on a test procedure… you appear to have ignored them completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I seem to have this issue also, on my my non-hdr display which I use as my main display. one of my displays has HDR, turning that off resolves it, but that's not exactly a solution.
It's only my browser having this issue when a white page is open, it destroys the contrast/brightness balance, moving it over to my HDR display fixes it though?
Removing my ICC profile and using the defaults hasn't resolved this issue for me either.

Comment: Disabling HDR seems to have resolved the problem, or at least until a patch is released, given the above it suggests that HDR is being applied to a Non-HDR screen.

Comment: This seems to be a comment rather than a solution. Removing the interogation mark (`?`) might help as it make it seem as if you are also asking for help about the same issue...